# AdS/CFT-oriented reviews of experimental techniques?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, ads-cft, experimental-technique

I am doing a PhD in AdS/CMT. In order to have a better understating of the physics of the systems the correspondence aims to describe, I am looking for accessible reviews or online seminars about the mostly commonly used experimental techniques for probing strongly coupled materials such as the cuprates in their strange metal phase.

Comment: Try searching on Inspire Hep, if you didn't do so already.

Comment: you're specifically interested in reviews of the methods (e.g. ARPES) aimed at HEP and not the experiments themselves?

Comment: Well, I’m interested in experiments as well. But to keep it simple I naively thought that getting informed on the recent experimental techniques to probe strongly coupled systems would have been the zeroth order step to understand experiments.